# Data on things like tag views and upvote fractions

Tags: discussion, tags, data-visualization, site-statistics, data-explorer

Is it possible to see (or generate / retrieve) data on things like which tags are the most widely viewed ones on CV, or what fraction of answers receive an upvote (or the distribution of upvotes on answers)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stack Exchange system has a [data site](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (more information [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/help)).  There you can get data on any of the network sites.  You will need to extend your account to the data site, and know SQL, but then this should be possible.

Comment: Also they release entire dumps of the same data available via the explorer (update every few months I think), https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.